# Automatically add new into term store

Tags: managed-metadata, term-store, managed-metadata-service

When one has metadata column connected to open term store, you can add new items into that store but you have to open the popup window. Is it possible to add a new keyword when the user enters a keyword that is not present in the term store yet?